# How do you use the Immediate Window to test a VB function?

Tags: vb.net

How do you use the Immediate Window to test a VB public function?

Comment: `Dim x = MyFunction()`  `Debug.Print(x)` or `Debug.Print(x.ToString)` if you function is returning something other than a string. This is always better than using MessageBox.Show() which could be left in release version by mistake. (blush)

Comment: You need to debug and have a breakpoint in the scope where this function is accessible. Did you consider to write automated unit test for this public function instead of testing it manually.

Comment: @Fabio Are your referring to Debug.Print? No breakpoint necessary. It just prints in the Immediate window.

Comment: No I am referring to debug breakpoint and when execution stops on a breakpoint you can write and execute code in Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like:

- put a breakpoint
- write some valid code in the immediate window - it has to be code that would work at that moment in the main flow of the program (where the execution is stopped now)
- here we have a function (C# but same difference), Add - it adds two numbers
- writing `?Add(1,3)` in the immediate window, produces 4
- the `?` prefix is a shortcut for `>Debug.Print`

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019